What did I do wrong in the iptables?
I'm trying to route all the traffic to my ShadowSocks tproxy access point by configure iptables, however not just the traffic didn't been route to the proxy, I don't think it did anything at all. I did the following commands to configure iptables and start ShadowSocks Tproxy(ss-redir). Note that I was following Shadowsocks's Github page
# Create new chain
iptables -t nat -N SHADOWSOCKS
iptables -t mangle -N SHADOWSOCKS

# Ignore your shadowsocks server's addresses
# It's very IMPORTANT, just be careful.
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d ServerIP -j RETURN

# Ignore LANs and any other addresses you'd like to bypass the proxy
# See Wikipedia and RFC5735 for full list of reserved networks.
# See ashi009/bestroutetb for a highly optimized CHN route list.
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to shadowsocks's local port
iptables -t nat -A SHADOWSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

# Add any UDP rules
ip route add local default dev lo table 100
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
iptables -t mangle -A SHADOWSOCKS -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 0x01/0x01

# Apply the rules
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j SHADOWSOCKS
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j SHADOWSOCKS

# Start the shadowsocks-redir
ss-redir -s SeverIP -p SeverPort -m chacha20-ietf-poly1305 -k 6d2b5b66-0d3f-4189-a547-501eb658879a -b 127.0.0.1 -l 12345 --no-delay -v -u T </dev/null &>>/var/log/ss-redir.log &

All the commands didn't return error, so I did a check to see current configuration
$ iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 524 packets, 204K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 SHADOWSOCKS  6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain SHADOWSOCKS (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            120.233.31.53       
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8           
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8          
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            169.254.0.0/16      
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.0.0/12       
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/16      
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         
    0     0 RETURN     0    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/4         
    0     0 REDIRECT   6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            redir ports 12345

After all this configuration, I expected to see the iptables redirecting all my networks to the local shadowsocks server and port 12345, but nothing was rerouted, all the packages is just routed perfectly like before I set the NAT. The NAT config somehow didn't do anything.
